# Term Filter in array only consider the last item?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search document in elastic search which has either tag a or b or c with the following query. But it always return the document which has only c and ignore a or b. Any one can help it out?

```
"filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "tags": ['a','b','c']
                }
            },
            "query": {
                match: {
                    rawText: 'filter'
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: strange , sorry for the obvious question but do the documents with "a"/"b" have  *filter* in the *rawText*

Answer (score 15):

In Elasticsearch, there is a difference between the term and the terms filter.

Term Filter:

```
{
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "term" : { "user" : "kimchy"}
        }
    }
}
```

Terms Filter:

```
{
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : {
                "user" : ["kimchy", "elasticsearch"],
                "execution" : "bool",
                "_cache": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try using the terms filter.

Answer (score 5):

> With *term*: All given elements must match
>
> See the official documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-term-filter.html

Or this:

> With *terms*: Min. one of the given elements must match
>
> See the official documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html

You asked for term/terms filter. Using term/terms in queries has another interpretation!

Comment: As of Elasticsearch 2.2.0, "[term] query does not support array of values"